# Parametric motion question

Tags: calculus, parametric

What exactly happens when both $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}$ and $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}$ equal zero?

I know that if $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t} =0$ then its a vertical tangent with $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t} \neq 0$

and if $\frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\mathrm{d}t}=0$ then its a horizontal tangent if $\frac{\mathrm{d}y}{\mathrm{d}t}\neq 0$.

Do you apply L'Hoptial rule to see if it is a tangent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{\frac {dy}{dt}}{\frac{dx}{dt}}$$

In your case, that means $\dfrac{dy}{dx}$ is of indeterminant form.

If both derivatives are zero, the tangent vector does not have a well-defined direction; in physical terms this indicates that the moving point has "slowed down" to a halt at the time $t$.

In this case, I would express the parametrization as a function of $x$ by solving for $t$ in the parametrization of $x(t)$, and substituting $t(x)$ into the parametrization of $y$ to get an equation in terms of $x$ and $y$, then differentiate to find $dy/dx$ directly.

Comment: Thanks, the "slowed down" to a halt, is what I was looking for.  I know how to manipulate the equations, but didn't really understand what it means.  Thanks for that detail.

Comment: You're welcome!